# mysqldump: how to fetch dependent rows

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like a snapshot of a live MySQL DB to work with on my development machine. The problem is that the DB is too large, so my thought was to execute:

```
mysqldump [connection-info-here] --no-autocommit --where="1 limit 1000" mydb > /dump.sql
```

I think this will give me the first thousand rows of every table in database `mydb`.  I anticipate that the resulting dataset will break a lot of foreign key constraints since some records will be missing. As a result the application I mean to run on the dev machine will fail.

Is there a way to `mysqldump` a sample of the database while ensuring that all records dumped abide by key constraints? (for instance if a foreign key is dumped, the matching record in the foreign table will also be dumped).

If that isn't possible, how do you guys deal with this problem?

Comment: I really join you, BeetleJuice in crying out for a way of doing this "automatically". As I said under @Bill's question, if MySQL can find and cascade-delete all dependent rows (recursively) when I delete a given key, it really should be able to find all those dependent rows for me if I supply the key in question!

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no option for mysqldump to dump only rows that match in foreign key relationships. You already know about the `--where` option, and that won't do it.

I've had the same task as you, to dump a subset of data but only data that is related. For example, for creating a test instance.

I've been using MySQL for many years, I've worked as a MySQL consultant and trainer, and I try to keep up with current tools. I have never heard of any MySQL tool that does this operation.

The only solution I can suggest is to write your own script to dump table by table using `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE`.

It's sometimes easier to write a custom script just for your specific schema, than for someone to write a general-purpose tool that works for everyone's schema.

How I have dealt with this problem in the past is I don't copy data from the live database. I find some other way to create a subset of fake data for testing. It's probably better to create synthetic data anyway, because then you don't risk accidentally using live data in your dev/test environment, in case some of it is private data.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I figured I couldn't be the first to face this problem so others must have solved it already.  I'm surprised to hear that there isn't a clean solution given how old and how popular MySQL is.

Comment: Bill something just occurred to me: there are a ton of [DB management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools) and many of them will let you backup tables or databases to an `.sql` file. Have you ever heard of one of them having this capability? (to fetch dependent records given a starting set of records)

Comment: No, I've never heard of a tool to do this automatically. It's too difficult to design a tool to do this and work with any possible schema. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/tool-to-export-data-with-all-relational-data for a similar question.

Comment: It shouldn't bee "too difficult", sir. If we're indeed talking about data related according to definite foreign key constraints. It's sooooo frustrating to hear this dead-end conclusion. This is a very regular kind of requirement in reality. If MySQL can find and cascade-delete all dependent rows when I delete a given key, it really should be able to find all those dependent rows for me when I supply the key in question!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo, Right, it's easy if you can design the schema, and make a backup tool that is used only for your schema or similar schemas. But making a general-purpose tool that can work with *any* schema design is much harder. For example, what if there are no foreign key constraints? To be honest, this describes all of MySQL sites that I have worked on.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo, Anyway, if you think it is so easy, be my guest and develop this tool yourself. I expect you can develop the tool, but then you will get 500 feature requests to handle weird cases that you didn't think of. You may implement some of these requests as options in your tool, and you may decline others. But it will be far more complex than you think.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo, I don't mean to make you feel frustrated. I'm just saying a generally reusable tool doesn't exist yet because it's much easier to develop it for *one* database, and that naturally means it is not reusable.

Comment: The point is, am talking about (and was very clear about) the case where foreign key constraints *are* indeed defined. Thanks anyhow.